# Directed graph, set of even nodes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let D=(V,E) be a finite directed graph. We define a set of even nodes in D=(V,E) a not null set $S ⊆ V$ with property $$|v^+ ∩ S| ≡ 0 ( mod 2 ), ∀v ∈ V.$$
$$v^+ = \{w ∈ V |(v, w) ∈ E\}$$
Now, If D=(V,E) is a directed graph with no isolated nodes(from every node there is at least one edge entering and one exiting) how do we prove that in D we don't have a set of even nodes?

Comment: Why can’t you have $1\longleftrightarrow 2\longleftrightarrow 3$, with $S=\{1,3\}$? Then $2^+=S$ has cardinality $2$, and $1^+\cap S=3^+\cap S=\varnothing$ has cardinality $0$, both even

Comment: Question: if $v$ has no adiacent nodes then $v^+ = \emptyset$ or $v^+ = \{ \emptyset \}$ because $|\{ \emptyset \}| = 1$?

Comment: If there is no edge leaving $v$, $v^+=\varnothing$; its cardinality is $0$. In fact $|v^+|$ is always the out-degree of $v$, and $|v^-|$ is always the in-degree of $v$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you